# Issue with using LocalStorage in PhoneGap for Android

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage, phonegap-plugins, html5-appcache

To resolve : Application error - A network error occurred. (file:///android_asset/www/messagedetails.html?Id=29) in Android 4.0,I am using LocalStorage.
This approach gave me the solution for the problem.But when the App is not run for long time or kept on hold., I am facing the issue again.
I am not able to navigate from one page to another page. :(

I added the code to clear the App cache , is it the right approach???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you are experiencing the "Unknown Chromium Error -6" issue. It's a known error in the Android 4.0 release that the file-URL can't contain parameters. (See further here: [Android 4.0 Issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535)). There are a number of possible solutions;

1. Redesign to use LocalStorage for passing parameters around.
2. Upgrading PhoneGap to 1.7+ (Cordova), seem to solve the issue. I haven't tried.

Hope it helps.